# How to solve for k to get equal roots in a composite function

Tags: functions

I am given:

$f(x) = 4x-2k\ $ and $\ g(x) = \dfrac{9}{2-x}$ ($x \not = 2$)

The question is:

Find the values for k for which the equation $fg(x) = x$ has two equal roots.

So $f(g(x))=\dfrac{4\cdot (9)}{2-x} -2k = \dfrac{36}{2-x} -2k$

$k$ is given as a constant (this means it is a number, and does not include variables?)

In the past I have used the discriminant of the quadratic formula to solve if something has equal roots. I'm not too sure what to do with this equation.

Comment: Please ignore the **, the italicizing seems to occur inconsistently :(

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please, you latex: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: is there a difference between $F,G,f,g$?

Comment: No, they indicate the same, just inconsistency on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(g(x))=\dfrac{36}{2-x} -2k$

$f(g(x))=x\rightarrow \dfrac{36}{2-x} -2k=x \rightarrow x^2 - 2x(1 - k) - 4(k - 9) = 0$

Solution for $x$ are equal if and only if discriminant $\Delta=0$

$4(1-k)^2+16(k-9)=0$

$k^2+2k-35=0\rightarrow k_1=-7;\;k_2=5$

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I'm still trying to figure out, however, how you went from what I originally found, to the step containing x^2 (and all the rest). Also, what is the significance of f(g(x) = x? I haven't seen that used before.

Comment: Ah, ok. I finally figured it out! It was mainly the f(g(x)) = x that I was confused by because it seemed odd. Thanks again :)